# how to implement toolbar in ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement toolbar in ionic which should look like same as this given in bootstrap .
http://jsfiddle.net/wmDL8/17/

I need to implement toolbar in ionic same as above in fiddle which is implemented in bootstrap.I tried it but my button are taking whole width I need equal space take from left and right .And user should able to add active class so that it know which button is selected and which is not
can we implement toolbar in ionic

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJRJLj

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
  <div class="buttons">
    <i style="font-size:30px;" class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>

</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
<div class="button-bar">
  <a class="button">Command1</a>
  <a class="button">Command2</a>
  <a class="button">Command3</a>
</div></ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your CSS `padding-left` and `padding-right` for your `button-bar` div:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOgOvV

```
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Tabs Example</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
  <div class="buttons">
    <i style="font-size:30px;" class='icon ion-chevron-left'></i>
  </div>
  <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>

</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
<div class="button-bar">
  <a class="button">First</a>
  <a class="button">Second</a>
  <a class="button">Third</a>
  <a class="button">fourth</a>
</div></ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.button-bar {
  padding-left:10%;
  padding-right:10%;
}
```

Image:

[image]

You can change the percentage to whatever you need it to eventually be.

Comment: thanks great answer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJRJLj.But how user know which button is active mean I need to add active class on button click .when user click on any button it become green and other become disable

Answer (score 0):

add a padding to your button-bar class with the desired value :

```
.button-bar {
  padding-left:10%;
  padding-right:10%;
}
```

Comment: @aorfervre thanks great answer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJRJLj.But how user know which button is active mean I need to add active class on button click .when user click on any button it become green and other become disable